# TextBoxGrid/Tabular View in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

Hi I need to make a text grid to display some data.
The requirement is as follows. The grid will always be n by n (a square).

1. Each cell in the grid needs to display 2 lines of data
2. 1st line of each cell is a 3 char identifier like ABC Font size 8
3. 2nd line of each cell needs to be 4 digit decimal number xx.yy Font size 6
4. Each cell background needs to be colour coded accoring to the xx.yy value Basically I need an excel style value based conditional formatting
5. I would like to be able to update each cell with a Control.Update (row,column, values) type function or a Control[row][column] = values type property.

So far I have looked at Gatagridviews but I cannot seem to find a way to implement multi line text entries with different font sizes

Before I decide to write my own control in C# and reinvent the wheel,is there a simpler way to do this. Please note I specifically need each cell to have 2 lines of text and each line of text has a different font size.

My approach will be to create NxNx2 text boxes and the play around with their formatting wrapping this entire mess in a class and then using it in a form with.

But as you can see if I am dealing with a 40X40 data grid this will result in 3200 text boxes. I don't think my approach is the best/correct way to go. Not to mention how difficult it will be to format this as a nice big Square.

PS. I have **0** knowledge of WPF and I have written most of my GUI in c# already

Comment: I usually create a DataTable and then use DatGridView.  The make the DataTable the DataSource of the DataTable.  See my answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724185/how-to-get-the-highest-lowest-and-average-values-from-a-param-tag-in-xml-stri/51725096#51725096  Then use datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Is this for viewing only, or do you need to be able to click and edit?

Comment: @pritaeas viewing only no edit required

Comment: @jdweng how do I set the font and colour of the cell?

Comment: I'd probably use a customcontrol in a grid. Create a custom control that contains two labels and your almost where you need to be.

Comment: @pritaeas after creating a customer control I will need to create n^2 instances if this controls correct? Seems tedious

Comment: If you don't want that then create a single customcontrol that draws the text on the canvas instead.

Comment: See msdn.  Set default before filling : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-font-and-color-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Comment: [RichTextBox Cell in a DataGridView](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView-2)